# Accessing a MongoDb with Xamarin App, time out error occurs

Tags: mongodb, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin app in C#, where i am trying to access a MongoDB database and perform basic CRUD actions. However, when i try to access the database when running the app, for example performing a create user method, the application crashes.

I know the code works, as i have another plain file that has the same code to access the database but with no Xamarin aspects. It is simply run in a .cs file, and accessing the database works completely. Is there something unique about Xamarin that means i cannot perform actions on the database or even access?

When i try run the code, i click a button to try perform a CRUD action. I excpect to be able to access the database and make changes, like in my other file however, however the app crashes.

The errors i get when trying to perform CRUD actions are: "[Choreographer] Skipped 109 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread." and "**System.TimeoutException:** 'A timeout occurred after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector"

Could this be because there are too many actions being performed on the main thread, causing it to skip frames and crash? Would multi-threading solve this? If so how would I do that?

My question:
What can I change so that I can access the database when running the app?

Notes:
It seems i can connect to the database, however i cannot make changes or access it.
I have tried to run the app on my physical phone; problem still persists.

The code is as follows:
DatabaseOperations.cs:

```
namespace XamerinMongoDBTest
{
    class DatabaseOperation
    {
        private const string ConnectionString = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017";
        private const string databaseName = "DBTesterAllPartsWA";
        private const string UserCollection = "users";

        private IMongoCollection<T> ConnectToMongo<T>(in string collection)
        {
            var client = new MongoClient(ConnectionString);//creating a new client with database
            var db = client.GetDatabase(databaseName);
            return db.GetCollection<T>(collection);
        }

        public Task CreateUser(Users user)
        {
            var usersCollection = ConnectToMongo<Users>(UserCollection);
            var newUser = usersCollection.InsertOneAsync(user);//Inserting the new user into the databse
            return newUser;
        }
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
namespace XamerinMongoDBTest
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DatabaseOperation db = new DatabaseOperation();//Connecting to the DB

            List<string> InterestsList = new List<string>();

            InterestsList.Add("Gaming");
            InterestsList.Add("Skiing");
            InterestsList.Add("Music");

            BsonArray bArray = new BsonArray();
            foreach (var term in InterestsList)
            {
                bArray.Add(term);
            }

            //Adding a User
***            await db.CreateUser(new Users() { Username = "Sam Brown", Display_Name = "SamP35", Password = "P3465", Email = "Sam534@gmail.com", Interests = bArray });


        }
    }
}
```

*** This is the point where the program crashes.
That same line of code works in a non Xamarin environment.

Comment: do not use `localhost`.  Use the real IP or FQDN of the server.  This has been discussed numerous times